# Proper Way to Insert Strings to a SQLAlchemy Unicode Column

Tags: python, unicode, sqlalchemy, insertion

I have a SQLAlchemy model with a Unicode column. I sometimes insert unicode values to it (u'Value'), but also sometimes insert ASCII strings. What is the best way to go about this? When I insert ASCII strings with special characters I get this warning:

```
SAWarning: Unicode type received non-unicode bind param value ...
```

How do I avoid this? What is the proper way to insert my different types of strings?

Answer (score 5):

Thre are several options:

1. Disable all SQLAlchemy warnings with `warnings.simplefilter('ignore', sqlalchemy.exc.SAWarning)`.
2. Disable only this warning with more specific filter spec by module and lineno or message, e.g. `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '^Unicode type received non-unicode bind param value', sqlalchemy.exc.SAWarning)`.
3. Use `String(convert_unicode=True)` instead of `Unicode` type.
4. Rethink the problem and change your code to use unicode even for ASCII strings.

Comment: You attemping delete problem instead of solving it.About number 3: Official documentation of `sqlalchemy` say use `Unicode type` but you say use `String(convert_unicode=True)` , i have same problem , but i don't think sqlalchemy solve with `disable warning` because it has `clean code` not `dirty`.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your table class and constructor as such:

```
class User(declarative_base()):
    _tablename__ = 'user'
    name = Column(Unicode(200, convert_unicode=False))
    textfield = Column(UnicodeText(convert_unicode=False))

user = Table('user', MetaData(),
Column('name', Unicode(200, convert_unicode=False), nullable=False),
Column('textfield', UnicodeText(convert_unicode=False), nullable=False),
)
```

Of course, you should not forget to attach `URI+"charset=utf8"` for `create_engine function`